# Could someone explain how Blender output colors

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, color-management

I'm newbie in the Blender, and can't understand why colors are adjusted during output.

Here is mine compositor scheme
[image: wrong colors]

As you can see, the R channel equals to 0.4 in the Combine RGBA Node, but in output it's 170 of 255, ie 0.666. Why does this happen?

Have to mention, it is purely 170 all over the rendered image, so it's not a compression artifact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, solved ! :)

Thanks to the user @cegaton !
Here is what he wrote to comment 1st answer:

> @m.ardito The important information you left out
>   of the picture. What you are showing are the scene referred values in
>   32bit float:The compositor works with scene referred values: unbound
>   linear data. Data is then processed through a display transform
>   (determined in the Color Management section) and converted to Display
>   referred data (in a scale from 0 to 1) The default transform is to
>   sRGB and is not a linear transform. That is true for images saved in 8
>   bits or 16 bit. The only format that gets saved bypassing the display
>   transform is OpenEXR

So after i set Properties editor ‣ Scene ‣ Color ‣ Display Device to none, all looks correct. Value 102 of 255 is 0.4.

Thank for the help you both @cegaton and @m.ardito !

[image]

Comment: Btw, that doesn't solve alpha-premultiplication, when each channel is divided by alpha during output, but OpenEXR does

Comment: By convention, RGB alpha encoded imagery should be associated (aka premultplied) alpha as that is the only real-world analogous alpha format, as well as being the only format that works appropriately for pixel pushers, with a small caveat. Unassociated (aka key or straight alpha) is an unsuitable alpha format for image makers. Learning how and why this is true is a critical step one's ability to craft imagery.

Comment: @troy_s i just encode some info into the RGB channels and don't want the alpha channel affects them, this is an original problem that i was going to solve https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87818/extracting-refraction-info-and-mix

Comment: “don't want the alpha channel affects them” isn't how alpha works. Further, as said numerous times elsewhere, "None" is not the method to achieve proper output. The whole thing is a huge godforsaken mess with regards to how colour and light are modeled to interact. Setting to “None” implies you are using a whacked nonlinear reference.

Comment: @troy_s Well, do you know other ways to archive this goal ?

Comment: Yes. But to start, you'll have to figure out what a colour is, what it means, and why it is handled the way it is within Blender. Happy to help. Cover a bit of ground on your own. There is a wealth of good information on here. Start looking at "sRGB" and where it leads.

Comment: @troy_s actually I've solved this already (see the link above), and now alpha is 255, so it does not affect other channels, however i found that it can be solved with OpenEXR, but its interesting, go on. Btw was trying to multiply all the channels by alpha, but without success :(

Comment: Have a peek at the answer I just posted. It might help you understand scene referred values versus display referred. Alpha is also a whole tricky beast unto itself, but understanding the nuances of the core models will help immensely. Your alpha issue would have been solved if you simply used associated alpha and RGB.

Comment: @troy_s i'm not going to get in details of how the Blender is working on alpha, however was trying to debug it according to this case, but only thing i've found is that it uses 3rd party library for output. Anyway, how the associated alpha can be set in the Blender UI ?

Comment: Raytracing engines can only generate associated (aka less useful term "premultiplied"). Some awful formats such as PNG can only encode unassociated (less useful term "straight" or "key"). If you save as EXR, your alpha is assumed associated by convention. Your original question has to do with nonlinear transfer functions however, and it cascades into "Why linearize colours?"

Comment: @troy_s I see, thanks for the info ! Actually i had to encode data in all 4 channels by compositor, and seems only OpenEXR can do this without modifications. There is a C# lib on github to read OpenEXR, so i use it to read pure RGBA